# Find a minimal sufficient statistic for $\mu$ and show that it's not complete.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots\stackrel{i.i.d.}{\sim}N(\mu,\mu^2)$.

**Exercise:** 
Find a minimal sufficient statistic for $\mu$ and show that it's not complete.

*What I've tried:*

Let $T(X) = (X_1-\mu, \ldots, X_n-\mu)$, I believe that $T(X)$ is minimal sufficient. Let $f(T) = (n(X_1-\mu), \ldots, n(X_n -\mu))$. We have that $E(f(T)) = 0$, but $f(T) \neq 0$, so $T(X)$ is not complete.

**Question:** My answer seems a bit too straightforward and I'm pretty sure that I've done something wrong or misunderstood some definition. Is this answer correct? If not; what would be a correct answer?

Thanks in advance.